# I am using REST_controller in HMVC (CI3.1).

Tags: codeigniter

It is working correctly with MX_Controller.It is throwing error as 'Fatal error: Class 'CI_Template' not found' when using REST_Controller.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the inner workings of Codeigniter's third party add-on HMVC. However, the code base that I inherited is using it.

I ran in to the same issue when installing restserver, https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver which is what I assume you were also doing.

REST_Controller.php has this

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends \CI_Controller {
```

While I have never been able to get CI_Controller to work with this codebase, I now believe it is because of this HMVC. For those not familiar, HMVC is Hierarchical Model View Controller.

> Module Controllers can be used as normal Controllers or HMVC
>   Controllers and they can be used as widgets to help you build view
>   partials.

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

I did get REST_Controller.php working by changing the line to

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends \MX_Controller { // \CI_Controller {
```